# Visualize embedding in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I used tensorflow script [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) and I saved the model with tf.summary :
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./w2v/model.ckpt")

I visualize the embedding with tensorboard succesfully but I get indexes of words in the vector
[image]
How can I get the words in the embedding instead of indexes in the vocabulary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this answer:
[linking-tensorboard-embedding-metadata-to-checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708106/linking-tensorboard-embedding-metadata-to-checkpoint)

the problem was I tried o call tensorboard with logdir : "./w2v/model.ckpt"
I should called it only with "w2v/"